# Search in json nested fields (schema + query)

Tags: solr, lucene, riak

I got the following JSON stored in a Riak bucket which handle Solr research.

```
{
  "date" : 1535673489, 
  "customer" : {
     "name" : "X"
     "id" : 1205643
    }
}
```

And my `schema.xml` fields look like that for the moment

```
 <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="date" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" mult    iValued="true"/>
```

And the research on date works perfectly fine with query as

```
$RIAK_HOST/search/query/order?wt=json&q=date:[1535553489%20TO%201535599999]
```

Unfortunately I didn't found any documentation that explains how to properly field and query on sub field as `customer.name` or `customer.id`

**Edit**: As I found on the following post [Riak search schema and nested fields](http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2010-December/002647.html), it seems that I need to create the fields as follow:

```
<field name="customer_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" mult    iValued="true"/>
```

But then when I query on the fields, I got no answer to my request

**Edit 2**: I proceed to the following experimentation and I get no error from riak.

I uploaded the file

```
{
  "customer_name" : "toto", 
  "customer" : {
    "name" : "tata"
  }
}
```

And on research Riak obtained the result from the field `"toto"` and not the one from `"tata"`. Is it possible that the nesting research is unactivated or associated to another character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields you need to add to your `schema.xml` are as follows:

```
<field name="date" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="customer" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<field name="customer.name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="customer.id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

And then you need to query your index as follow:

```
$RIAK_HOST/search/query/order?wt=json&q=customer.name:t*
```

Comment: I think you forghet to put the as follow?

Comment: Thanks else do you know if I should query like: 
`q=customer.name:toto` or `q=customer_name:toto` 
In fact I just tested and the first one is the answer. Thanks

Comment: Yea. Thanks! The first one will work because that's the field we have declared in schema file.